# Using aria attribute in Angular component causes error

Tags: angular, angular-components, wai-aria

I have a clickable card that I would like to make into a component.  I want to create an `@Input` for the unique name (id) of the instance do that I can use `aria-labelledby` on the card's title:

```
    <div
      class="card card-default category-widget"
      id="{{ widgetID }}"
      matRipple
      aria-labelledby="{{widgetTitle}}"
      role="button"
      tabindex="0"
    >
      <div class="card-body category-widget-icon" aria-hidden="true">
        <i class="pbi-icon-outline pbi-wifi"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <h4 class="category-widget-title" id="{{ widgetTitle }}">Widget Title</h4>
        <p class="category-widget-description">
          Widget description text
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Except this throws the error:

`Can't bind to 'aria-labelledby' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.`

Without the `aria-labelledby`, the component works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead use `[attr.aria-labelledby]="widgetTitle"` because it's an adhoc attribute. Angular doesn't bake in anything for many attributes like it does for DOM properties, etc. So things like ARIA or say, `data-*` attributes need to be specified as an attribute via `attr.` and a one way binding.

Comment: Thanks.  Would the aria still work, since it's on the component content and not the instance itself?  In other words, the DOM has `<app-cat-widget>` with my card inside, but I'm going to apply the click handler to the `<app-cat-widget>` instance.

Comment: Ya it should be fine, though you can occasionally run into issues with attaching events to the component level's click area and sometimes need to add like `:host { display: block/inline-block/whatever the case }` to the component.scss so the hit area is where you expect in relation to its children elements.

Comment: @ChrisW. `"Angular doesn't bake in anything for many attributes like it does for DOM properties"`.  That's too bad.  The ARIA attributes **are** regular DOM properties.  They should be treated just like any other DOM property and if angular doesn't have anything baked in or treats them differently than other properties, I see that as a shortcoming of angular.

Comment: @slugolicious is it a shortcoming though? ....and actually, if we stay true to spec they **are** [attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA) to HTML DOM elements (not to correct you, but it's true, except landmark elements like `<nav>` etc that are ARIA by default). Either way, one simple change to the delivery of the requirements and we're easily able to adhere to all the regular accessibility standards you might require, or basically, angular's pretty neat. :)

Comment: Oh PS, the strange brew great white north Rick pic is excellent!

Comment: Finally, someone gets it. Take off, eh.